# Linq to entities does not recognize the method system.string get_Item

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to have an orderByExpression to passed to a function which uses it on the dbContext object in the entity framework

```
> Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
> Expression<Func<DbQuestion, string>> orderByExpression = r => dict[r.Id];
```

This throws the following error.

> Exception=Exceptions.DBConnectionException: LINQ
>   to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

I understand that I cannot access the [ ] in Linq to Sql queries. Can you please suggest an alternative or point me in the right direction?

Edit:

Few more details about the problem I am trying to solve:

The dict have 15-20 items and keys remain constant and only values change dynamically

I am trying to order the questions based on the range of r.Id i.e if floor(r.Id)==14 then I return "a" if it's between floor(r.Id)==15 then I return "b" and if it's between floor(r.id)==13 I return "c"(as decided by the values in the dict) this helps in ordering the rows

Here's the actual expression:

```
List<int> cqh;
List<int> iqh;
Expression<Func<DbQuestion, string>> orderByExpression = r => cqh.Contains(r.QuestionID)? dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] +"2"+Guid.NewGuid() :  
                    iqh.Contains(r.QuestionID)? dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] + "1"+Guid.NewGuid() :  
                    dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] + "0"+Guid.NewGuid();
```

Thanks,

Comment: How many items are in the dictionary ? Potentially a lot or just a few ?

Comment: usually 15-20 items

Comment: And these change dynamically ?

Comment: yeah keys do not change but values change dynamically

Comment: No I am trying to order the questions based on the range of r.Id i.e if 14<=r.Id<16 then I return "a" if it's between 16<=r.Id<18 then I return "b" this helps in ordering the rows

Comment: You can try to join your table with this dictionary `on table.Id = dict.Key` and then order by `dict.Value`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov  I am doing something like- Id is basically my searchKey and I want to have one range of values say 14<=id<16 to be coming front and 16<=id<18 next and something like 12<=id<14 coming later

Comment: But at this case you can still order by plain Id, if ranges increase

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I can't order by Id because it just doesn't depend on the value of Id. Please have a look at following case based on the earlier example where in id = 16 coming after id=14. and id = 12 coming after id=16

Comment: In the edit you say 14<=r.Id<16, how do 14 and 16 come from the dic ? the key I understood is the id, so that could be the start of the range, but where does the end of the range come from ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir my bad. I am actually taking a floor of r.Id (float) and checking if it's 14, 15, 16 which is the key in the dictionary

Comment: So the correct condition would be dict[(int)r.Id]; ?

Comment: Yes for more clarity let me add the actual expression that I am trying to build to the question

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual expression that I am using

Comment: Wow .. that is one big expression. I will update my answer, building it all manually is not a good option in this case, I will try to do it with a Visitor.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I just have a question. Can't I just move this entire logic to another function in the same class and just build an expression tree which is basically a method call expression to this function? But I doubt if this works because essentially isn't it the same thing i.e if we build the expression tree manually or it getting automatically built from a lambda expressions?

Comment: No you can't call a C# function in SQL, at least not like this, when EF converts the query it will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options, that stay with LINQ to Entities

1. Put the data in the dictionary in a separate table, save it, and then join the table. This solution can apply even if you need to have per query data.

Example:

```
public class SortKey
{
    [Key]
    public int SortKeyId { get; set; }
    public long SearchId { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string SortId { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new Db())
{
    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    long searchId = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // Simplfied, either use a guid or a FK to another table
    db.Keys.AddRange(dict.Select(kv => new SortKey { SearchId = searchId, EntityId = kv.Key, SortId = kv.Value }));
    db.SaveChanges();

    var query = from e in db.Entity
                join k in db.Keys.Where(k => k.SearchId == searchId) on (int)e.Id equals k.EntityId
                orderby k.SortId
                select e;
}

// Cleanup the sort key table
```

2. Build the condition dynamically. This can be achieved using Expression manipulation

Example:

```
Expression exp = Expression.Constant(""); //Default order key
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity));
foreach (var kv in dict)
{
    exp = Expression.Condition(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, p.Type.GetProperty("Id")), typeof(int)
            ),
            Expression.Constant(kv.Key)
        ),
        Expression.Constant(kv.Value),
        exp
    );
}

var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, string>>(exp, p);

var query = db.Entity.OrderBy(orderByExp);
```

Which option you use depend on the amount of data in the dictionary. The condition built for the `OrderBy` might get very inefficient for a large amount of data

**Edit**

Based on the changed question, you can use an expression visitor to replace the dic[...] call with a conditional testing for each value in the dictionary. The advantage of this approach is that you can easily change the expression, the replace will work the same way

The class:

```
class DictionaryReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if(node.Object != null && node.Object.Type == typeof(Dictionary<int, string>) && node.Method.Name == "get_Item")
        {
            Expression exp = Expression.Constant(""); //Default order key
            // Compile the tahrget of the index and execute it to get the value
            // If you know there is a single dictionary you could replace this with a class property intead and set it from the Visit call site, 
            // but this is the more general appraoch
            var dict = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dictionary<int, string>>>(node.Object).Compile()();
            foreach (var kv in dict)
            {
                exp = Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        node.Arguments.Single(),
                        Expression.Constant(kv.Key)
                    ),
                    Expression.Constant(kv.Value),
                    exp
                );
            }

            return exp;
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, string>> orderByExpression = r => cqh.Contains(r.QuestionID) ? dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] + "2" + Guid.NewGuid() :
        iqh.Contains(r.QuestionID) ? dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] + "1" + Guid.NewGuid() :
        dict[(int)Math.Floor(r.SearchKey1)] + "0" + Guid.NewGuid();
var replace = (Expression<Func<Entity, string>>)new DictionaryReplaceVisitor().Visit(orderByExpression);

var query = db.Entity.OrderBy(replace).ToString();
```

The resulting SQL will not be pretty but it should work.

**Solution 3:**

If the amount of data is not very big, you can do a `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` on the query and do the ordering in memory (by calling the `OrderBy` after one of the above methods). It might actually perform better in this case

Comment: Can be a bit improved, since OP needs to sort based on range of id, not on individual ids. But of course that answers question that was actually asked.

Comment: @Evk you are right based on the comments. But I read the question which did not mention the range, only the dictionary and started writing the code.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I am really sorry for wasting peer developers time. Let me add more details to the question

Comment: @router I understand from the comments that ultimately the sortkey is going to be based more on a range then a dictionary. Both solutions still apply in principle, you would need to have the range for the first in the table, and for the second you need to build the range condition. If you add details I can change the code

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  I don't have the option of creating another DB right now. So probably am gonna stick with Expression building (which is a pain for me) if no other way is possible

Comment: @router I don't see one. Leave the question open for a while longer, maybe someone else will come up with something.

Comment: @router you can just copy expressions code from this answer - no pain here.

Comment: @router I changed the answer to use the new expression. Also a third solution would be to do the sorting in memory if the amount of data is limited

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Can't I simply use your first example by replacing Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, p.Type.GetProperty("Id")) with the expression for (int)floor(p.id) ? I think the floor and int cast are allowed in sql

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I get it. It would be tedious to build the rest of the expression in a similar fashion. right?

Comment: Yes it would be tedious, error prone and hard to maintain to build it up manually, it's simpler this way. Also floor and int cast are the same in this case.